# Click goes throught layer after Kinetic.Node.create()

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I'm importing a JSON layer to the stage.

```
var loadedobject = Kinetic.Node.create(data);
        maplayer.add(loadedobject);
```

Code to change the content what I'm importing seems to do like fine: (BTW: .maplayer2 is the layer I have imported)

```
maplayer.get('.maplayer2')[0].setScale(browserwidthdifference);
            maplayer.get('.maplayer2')[0].setY(browserheight/2);
            maplayer.setDraggable(true);
```

However if do the code below it doesn't work:

```
maplayer.on('click', function() {
                console.log('help');    
            });


maplayer.get('.maplayer2')[0].on('click', function() {
                console.log('help');    
            });
```

I have let the background black of the  imported layer so I can see the detection. However if I do:

```
backgroundlayer.on('click', function() {
                console.log('help');    
            });
```

I get the click responses even if I click on the imported layer which is clearly on top of the other layer. `maplayer.moveToTop()` doens't work either. All alternations work but the click events won't work with the imported object.

If I create another object in maplayer it will response to it when I click on it, but the imported layer in the layer will still be not detected.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save all objects within a group object it will work fine! So when you save things do not do it within a Layer but in a Group object.